# Push notification problem in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I tried the following tutorials to create the push notification in Windows Phone 7.

http://www.sgtconker.com/2010/03/article-windows-phone-7-push-notifications/

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

I can create the channel uri in the WP7 emulator without any error.

However, when I post the push notification from the server to the channel uri. I could only receive the 404 error.

Could anyone give me some help ?

Thanks.

=====

Update 1 (28-Oct):

Thank you very much for the answers.

After I read the latest resources and sample codes, I just sent a push notification to the WP7 emulator successfully.

The channel setup part in WP7 does not change much in the latest SDK.

**The problem that I encountered before was from the POST message part of the sender.**

The following website is quite useful.

http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/02/a-really-long-post-about-the-windows-phone-7-push.aspx

He shows how to correcty build the POST message and it is very critical.

Also the channel uri that created before will expire, when the WP7 emulator (handset) turns off over an hour. Hence, we need to keep track of the channel uri and update the server once it changes.

Have a nice day.

=====

Update 2 (28-Oct):

I just created the POST message using cURL in Linux server, and successfully delivered it to the WP7 emulator by push notification.

Text encoding like ASCII-UTF-8 conversion issue was fixed too.

Comment: Hopefully you have got everything up and running by now, if not you may want to have a look at the Entile framework: http://coding-insomnia.com/entile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some changes to notification handling through the ctp and beta as Matt advices.

I'd recommend checking out this documentation for an overview, detailed code samples and response codes.

[Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Set Up a Notification Channel for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402556%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Send a Push Notification from a Web Service for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Also if you'd like to get some more overview I'd recommend checking out the [Mix 10](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/CL17) and [Tech Ed 2010 NA](http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/WPH305) talks by Peter Torr. If you'd like points in the video to skip forward to I can get these.

Answer (score 1):

The articles you refer to are very old and relate to the Beta and CTP versions of the tools. Unfortunately Push notifications is an area which saw much change before RTM/RTW.

Have a look at the up to date instructions on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537(v=VS.92).aspx. I suspect you'll have much better luck with instructions which match the current tools.