# Windows Phone 7 - Message based off of ANID

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am collecting ANIDs from my application and I was wondering is there a way to send the phone a message based off of ANIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean messages like notifications, the only way to do this is through the notification service, by creating a channel on the client and sending this to your web service. There's no mechanism by which the ANID can be used to avoid those steps.

[How to: Set Up a Notification Channel for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402556%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Send a Push Notification from a Web Service for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: That is what I'm finding out...  Do you happen to have a really easy example of how I can do notifications via channels?  The examples I'm finding don't answer all my questions and most of the examples don't seem to work..  So I need a very basic example.

Comment: The training kit has some stuff out of date from a change made in beta. The doco is up to date though, adding links.

Comment: I think I've asked this before, can you send a push notification from a PHP webservice?  I'm trying to modify that code you sent with the following: http://www.barattalo.it/2010/08/09/send-push-notification-to-iphone-with-php-and-pushme-to/  but it doesn't seem to be working....  Also will the emulator receive notifications from an outside source?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033939/push-notification-problem-in-windows-phone-7 as long as you can do http, you're in good shape