# Push Notification for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application for windows phone 7 where i need to add push notification whenever some new data has been added in the application from backend. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this? I googled it but didnt get much help. Please someone tell me the procedure for doing this

Comment: Have you checked this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033939/push-notification-problem-in-windows-phone-7?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can ASP.NET to send push notifications from a web browser. A sample for the same can be found in Windows Phone Dev Center Samples here at [MSDN Push Notification Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Toast-Notification-Sample-fb20ae13).

Alternatively, you can use PHP to send push notifications as well. An excellent library has been put up at [CodePlex](http://phpwindowsphonepush.codeplex.com/).

So the overall steps for achieving this would be as follows:

1. Inside the app, write code to implement Push Notifications by **creating a new push notification channel** and subscribing the device to that channel.
2. On successful subscription, the device gets a unique **Push Notification URI**
3. Use the Push Notification URI in ASP.NET sample page and send some dummy content. Or alternatively for PHP use the following code:

   $uri="**YOUR PUSH NOTIFICATION URI**";
   $notif=new WindowsPhonePushNotification($uri);
   $notif->push_toast("Title","Description");

This should briefly outline all the steps in setting up and receiving push notifications. The MSDN Sample is self sufficient if you are using ASP.NET. In case you want a step by step tutorial, you can further refer here at [C# Corner Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/working-with-toast-notification-in%C2%A0windows-phone-7/)